# Como ver lo que transmite motion( webcam server ) en una applicacion para android

Tags: java, android

Instalé *motion* ( servidor webcam para linux ) en una `raspberry pi3` , puedo acceder a esta cámara a través de la `IP` de la `raspberry` mas el puerto donde esta la cámara ejemplo : **192.168.1.35:8081**, esto me funciona perfecto en web , para  poder poner la campara en una pagina web solo hago esto `<img src="http://192.168.1.35:8081/">` y listo la cámara se ve en vivo en la pagina , luego intente hacerlo en una `app` utilizando `VideoView`, pero sale una alerta que dice no se puede mostrar el vídeo.

Tengo muy poca experiencia en `android` o cualquier lenguaje nativo. Alguien a intentado hacer algo parecido ?.
Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.
NOTA :
Ya agregué los permisos de internet y tambien probé con un vídeo que puse en una maquina de la misma red (`http://192.168.1.25/video.mp4` ) y si funciona.

**EL CODIGO JAVA**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {
    private static final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH=100;
    private TextView textViewEntradaVoz;
    private ImageButton buttonHablar;
    ProgressDialog mDialog;
    VideoView videoView;
    ImageButton btnpause;
    String VIDEO ="http://192.168.1.35:8081";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoView = findViewById(R.id.Straming);
        btnpause = findViewById(R.id.btnplay);
        textViewEntradaVoz = findViewById(R.id.textoEntrada);
        buttonHablar = findViewById(R.id.btnHablar);
        buttonHablar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                iniciarEntradaDeVoz();
            }
        });

        btnpause.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void iniciarEntradaDeVoz() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"HABLA");
        try{
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQ_CODE_SPEECH);
        }catch (Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    textViewEntradaVoz.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mDialog.setMessage("esto esto");
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDialog.show();
        try{
            if(!videoView.isPlaying()){

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(VIDEO);
                videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        btnpause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                videoView.pause();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                mp.setLooping(true);
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui la respuesta a mi propia pregunta , despues de un dia de investigacion  encontré esta  [libreria para android](https://github.com/perthcpe23/android-mjpeg-view)  es  muy sensilla de utilizar y todo me funciona correctamente.
ESPERO QUE LE SIRVA ALGUIEN MAS.

**AQUI EL CODIGO JAVA**

```
MjpegView viewer =  findViewById(R.id.mjpegview);

    viewer.setMode(MjpegView.MODE_FIT_WIDTH);
    viewer.setAdjustHeight(true);
    viewer.setUrl("LA URL DONDE ESTA TRANSMITIENDO LA CAMARA ");
    viewer.setRecycleBitmap(true);
    viewer.startStream();
```

**XML**

```
<com.longdo.mjpegviewer.MjpegView
        android:id="@+id/mjpegview"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="241dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnDerecha"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```